# Data in list order - any way to only use the list once?

Tags: mysql

On a page that displays the results of a user's criteria, I want to show only some columns of data (in the interest of speed) and then allow the user to add additional columns later as desired, and my code will use AJAX to get the data to fill in.  In the meantime, the underlying data that matches the criteria might have changed, and the visible table might have been resorted by jQuery, so rather than using the original WHERE clause again, I thought it would be safer to collect the IDs from the visible table and pass them to the query.  Consider this example of such a query:

```
SELECT t2.OtherField FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.JoinID=t2.JoinID
WHERE t1.MyID in (1417,2120,217,590,6566,11764)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(t1.MyID,'1417,2120,217,590,6566,11764')
```

Now imagine that the number of IDs in the list could be far more than that (hundreds, or even thousands if the user is not being thoughtful).  Repeating the same long list in `WHERE` and `FIND_IN_SET` seems excessive.  Is there a way to get the same result while using the list of IDs only once?  I tried this, but it didn't work (the first six results were older records, not the six in the list):

```
SELECT t2.OtherField FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.JoinID=t2.JoinID
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(t1.MyID,'1417,2120,217,590,6566,11764')
LIMIT 6
```

Or does it not even matter if the query is huge due to the repeated list?  Or, if I'm going about this all wrong and you have a different idea, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Why not return `MyID` in the query, and then have the AJAX client find the appropriate rows to insert the data in using this?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, and I'll do that if there's not another way.  I would definitely do it if it meant that I wouldn't need the ID collection at all, but I think I would still need it for the `WHERE` clause, because there might be rows in the visible table that no longer fit the original criteria (if someone else has changed data in the meantime).  So that would only eliminate the `ORDER BY` and replace it with a big chunk of (possibly slow) jQuery.  Maybe that's the way to go, but it's hard to predict the performance.

Comment: `$("#myTable").find("tr[data-myID="+id+"]")` shouldn't be very slow.